# Can a single stat do a sum for the time range without an interval?

Tags: grafana

I want to use a single stat box for displaying cumulative totals in a dashboard... For example, if a user chooses a date range of 1 hour, I want to show the count of all items in that hour and not all items in that hour divided by the number of intervals occurring in that hour.